# Linear regression results in columns for different rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, statistics, anaconda

My goal is to do a regression analysis for several rows and store the results in seperate columns, attached to my dataframe I load in.

So, I found the following code that gives me the results with one x and one y variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
df = pd.read_excel("Directory\File.xlsx")
x = df.iloc[0,:]
y= df.iloc[1,:]
scipy.stats.linregress(x,y)
```

This gives me the following results:

[image: result]

The initial dataframe for this example contains 3 rows and 24 columns.

[1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24];

[100    10  61  55  29  77  61  42  70  73  98  62  25  86  49  68  68  26  35  62  100 56  10  97];

[57 89  25  89  48  56  67  17  98  10  25  90  17  52  85  56  18  20  74  97  82  63  45  87]

The zero row is always the x-axe: the independent variable. The rows 1 and 2 are 
dependent variable, thus the y-axe. Now, I want to perform this regression analysis and for each row (from row 1 on) it has to calculate the results and append them to the dataframe. So in the end, we will have 5 additional columns with the slope, intercept, rvalue, p value and stderr per row.

I tried to iterate over every row with this piece of code (this makes a new dataframe which is also okay):

```
def linreg(row):
z = scipy.stats.linregress(x,y)
linreg_df = pd.DataFrame(z)
return(linreg_df)

full_dataframe = None

for index,row in df.iterrows():
z = linreg(index)
if full_dataframe is None: 
    full_dataframe = z.T
else: 
    full_dataframe = full_dataframe.append([z.T])


full_dataframe.to_excel('Directory\\File.xlsx')
```

But it gives me the following error:

[image: error]

Is there anyone who could tell me what I do wrong and what a proper solution is?

Thanks,

Steven

Answer (score 3):

Use `_asdict` method to convert the results of the lineregress to a OrderedDictionary, and then you can use that dictionary in the constructor for a pandas dataframe:

Here is a MCVE:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats


X = [1,2,3,4,7]
y = [2,4,6,9,13]

r = scipy.stats.linregress(X,y)

df = pd.DataFrame(r._asdict(), index=[0])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      slope  intercept    rvalue    pvalue   stderr
0  1.858491   0.481132  0.989413  0.001306  0.15739
```

#### Updated:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats

txt = StringIO("""1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
100 10 61 55 29 77 61 42 70 73 98 62 25 86 49 68 68 26 35 62 100 56 10 97
57 89 25 89 48 56 67 17 98 10 25 90 17 52 85 56 18 20 74 97 82 63 45 87""")
df = pd.read_csv(txt, sep='\s', header=None, engine='python')

fullll_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

for i,row in df.iloc[1:,:].iterrows():
    r = scipy.stats.linregress(df.iloc[0, :], row)
    full_dataframe = pd.concat([full_dataframe,pd.DataFrame(r._asdict(), index=[i])])

print(full_dataframe)
```

Output:

```
      slope  intercept    rvalue    pvalue    stderr
1  0.083478  58.123188  0.021827  0.919366  0.815204
2  0.399565  51.963768  0.096415  0.654034  0.879439
```

Comment: and I want it to do it for every row. How can I do this?

Comment: What is your X row?  And, your y row interates though the rest of of the dataframe?

Comment: my x row is row zero. my y row iterates indeed over the rest of the dataframe.

Comment: thanks Scott! I tried it with 3 rows, but he only gives me the one of the first two rows. Does the code needs to be adjusted ? I adjusted the values within df.iloc, but i doesnt seems to do anything

Comment: You source data dataframe has three rows?   then yes, the first row is X and you run two regressions on line 1 and line 2.  If your source dataframe has 4 rows, then you should get three regressions.  no modifications should be needed.

Comment: I want to make it generic, so even if I have 10000 rows. Row zero always has to be the X variable

Comment: it gives me the error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: You are trying to iterate over a series instead over a dataframe.

Comment: I have no idea what that means :D

Comment: You need to study pandas a bit more.   pd.Series nad pd.DataFrame have different methods.  iterrows is a dataframe method and not a series method.  That is what your error message is stating.